# Flutter Open Pdf File That Has Helvetica Font Doesn't Show Capital 'i' Character in PDF

Tags: flutter, pdf, flutter-font

Our flutter application has a feature that gets the response from server and this response has encrypted pdf content. We decode the response and it gives us base64 content. When I try to use OpenFile function, it opens the pdf but some Turkish characters are not visible.(Like capital 'i' , 'ş' etc.) I know the pdf content has Helvetica font and when we try another pdf in another page that has Montserrat font, it opens perfect. I don't have to permission to change Pdf font from the server, so is there a way to change font of the base64 content before the open pdf file ?

I tried pdf packages from pub.dev but most of packages are waiting string for the create pdf and I don't have.